# Необщепринятые сложносокращённые слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, сокращения

*Финрынки / фин. рынки*

*Экономтеория / эконом. теория*

По каким правилам нужно сокращать вышеприведённые и другие слова, для которых нет установленных сокращений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Финрынки или фин. рынки? Экономтеория или эконом. теория.***

Технология решения такова:

Если слово пишется слитно (**сложносокращенное** слово), то оно **должно быть в словаре**. Если его там нет, то надо ставить точку, но при этом применять правила сокращения.

1) Набираем в словаре на Грамоте.ру ФИН. **ФИН**... Первая часть сложных слов. Вносит зн. сл.: финансовый (1 зн.). Финагент, фининспектор, фининспекция, финотдел, финплан.

Проверяем наше слово (**набираем в том же словаре**): ***финрынки***. Ответ: такого слова нет, значит, надо использовать сокращение ***фин. рынки*** и ставить точку:

2) **ЭКОНОМ**... [от греч. oikonómikē - искусство ведения хозяйства] Первая часть сложных слов. Вносит зн. сл.: экономический. Экономгеография, экономреформа, экономсектор, экономсовет, экономсоветник.

Слова ***экономтеория*** нет, вывод тот же.

3) Правила сокращения http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters/86-rubric-10

Также на сайте есть документ Сокращение слов и словосочетаний по ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011.

4) Но в нашем случае сокращения ***фин. рынки, эконом. теория***  будут скорее верными, так как такие же сокращения используются в сложносокращенных словах.